# WebAPI [FromBody] always null

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, owin

I received a request like this.

```
POST /API/Event?EventID=15&UserID=1&Severity=5&DeptID=1&FlowTag=CE HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Host: localhost:8088
Content-Length: 9
Expect: 100-continue
Connection: Keep-Alive


HTTP/1.1 100 Continue


Desc=test
```

And my WebAPI interface is like this:

```
[Route("API/Event"), HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult StationCreateWorkItem(long EventID, long UserID, int Severity,
    long DeptID, string FlowTag, [FromBody] string Desc)
```

However, my Desc parameter is always NULL. May I know how can I retrieve the body content if there is no way for me to use [FromBody] in WebAPI (OWIN)

Sorry, I can't change the incoming message, because it was developed by another company.

Comment: I have found an alternate solution. Instead of using "[FromBody] string Desc", I have changed to "[FromBody] FormDataCollection Datas". And retrieve all parameters from the form body. Hopefully someone can recommend a better solution later.

Answer (score 9):

By default, Web API uses the following rules to bind parameters:

- If the parameter is a "simple" type, Web API tries to get the value
  from the URI.
- Simple types include the .NET primitive types (`int`, `bool`, `double`,
  and so forth), plus `TimeSpan`, `DateTime`, `Guid`, `decimal`, and
  `string`, plus any type with a type converter that can convert from a
  string.
- For complex types, Web API tries to read the value from the message
  body, using a media-type formatter.
- If you have a primitive type in the URI or if you have a complex
  type in the body, then you don't have to add any attributes (neither
  `[FromBody]` nor `[FromUri]`).
- At most, one parameter is allowed to read from the message body. So
  this will not work:

  ```
  public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody] int id, [FromBody] string name) { ... }
  ```

[Parameter Binding in ASP.NET Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api) (MSDN)

[How WebAPI does Parameter Binding](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jmstall/2012/04/16/how-webapi-does-parameter-binding/) (MSDN)

**Now the solution:**

```
POST /API/Event?EventID=15&UserID=1&Severity=5&DeptID=1&FlowTag=CE HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Host: localhost:8088
Content-Length: 9
Expect: 100-continue
Connection: Keep-Alive

HTTP/1.1 100 Continue

=test
```

> removed Desc

Comment: Thanks for the info, but unfortunately I cannot change the incoming message. Because it was done by another party.

Answer (score 5):

Well, you may want to do this for raw string data. If you use `HTTPClient.PostAsync`, you need to use `HttpRequest`/response instead of `[FromBody]`, like so:

```
[Route("value"), HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage Post(HttpRequestMessage value)
{
    var res = value.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
    return null;
}

HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
var content = new StringContent("boe");
var result = client.PostAsync(baseAddress + "api/value", content).Result;
```

The trick is the async part, and your `[FromBody]` is null, as it is a async post. You still need to read the data out of the request.

On the other hand, if you want "DTO" complex types, you can use the `[FromBody]` construction like so:

```
public class SomeDto
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

[Route("somedto"), HttpPost]
public void PostDto([FromBody]SomeDto value)
{

}
```

You call it like this:

```
var requestJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new SomeDto() { Name = "1" });
var content = new StringContent(requestJson);
content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
result = client.PostAsync(baseAddress + "api/somedto", content).Result;
```

Answer (score 2):

Lastly, you may want to use these:

```
[Route("valueparam/{value}"), HttpGet]
public void PostWithParam([FromUri]string value)
{
}
result = client.GetAsync(baseAddress + "api/valueparam/1").Result;
```

And:

```
[Route("valueparamfrombody"), HttpPost]
public void PostWithParam2([FromBody] JObject value1)
{
}


var req = new
{
   value1 = "1"
};
var obj = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(req);
content = new StringContent(obj);
content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");            
result = client.PostAsync(baseAddress + "api/valueparamfrombody", content).Result;
```

Answer (score 0):

In my [case](https://rexebin.medium.com/dotnet-webapi-frombody-receive-null-unexpectedly-3bc2f5a6da54), my model has a `Guid?` property, I send an empty string, so the parsing is failed and I get `null`.